# React set multiple states on an event

Tags: reactjs

I have a modal that when it is closed updates a state.  The modal also has a div which will be replaced if a button is clicked.  The button is replaced with a text area and 2 buttons (one of them a cancel.)  If the cancel is clicked, the state updates and the text area hides.  All good.  However, if the user closes the modal, then the state is not updated and the div is shown next time.
I am unsure of how to set 2 states on close for the modal, I think this could sort this issue.
Code has been updated as per @jsNoob suggestion:
Hint component has

```
  const [showModalProblemS_vid, setShowModalProblemS_vid] = useState(false);

<VideoModal showModal={showModalProblemS_vid} closeHandler={() => setShowModalProblemS_vid(false)} videoMessage={props.prob_s_vid} size='med'/>
```

So how to set a state which is not in the file is the issue

Modal Code below:

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import { useState } from 'react';

function VideoModal({showModal = false, closeHandler = () =>{}, videoMessage, content, size}) {

  const [confused, setConfused] = useState(false)
  
  return (
    <Modal
      size={size}
      show={showModal} 
      onHide={closeHandler}
      onClose={()=> {setConfused(false); closeHandler()}}
      backdrop="static"
      keyboard={false}
    >

    <Modal.Body>
      <video src={videoMessage} controls autoPlay></video> 
      <div>
        {confused ? (
        <div>
          What have you found confusing about this video?
          <textarea className='confusedText' rows="2"></textarea>          
          <Button className="confusedBtnSave">
            Save
          </Button>
          <Button className="confusedBtnCancel" onClick={()=>setConfused(false)}>
            Cancel
          </Button>          
        </div>
        ) : (
        <div>
          <Button className="confusedBtn" onClick={()=>setConfused(true)}>
            Confused?
          </Button>
        </div>
      )}
      </div>
      
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button variant="secondary" onClick={closeHandler}>
        Close
      </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
  )
}

export default VideoModal
```

Comment: On the child component, instead of: `onClose={()=>setConfused(false)}`, have you tried something like this: `onClose={()=> {setConfused(false); closeHandler()}}` - where `closeHandler()` is from the props (so, the parent, ie the `Hint` component, will send it like this: `closeHandler={() => setShowModalProblemS_vid(false)}`). Please share your feedback on what happens if you try these.

Comment: @jsN00b - updated code to show what I think you meant - however this behaves exactly the same way as it was before

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got this working.  I had to use the following:

```
onClick={() => {onClose(); setConfused(false)}}
```

note the semi-colon between the states

Answer (score 2):

Well to set multiple states you can do that inline

```
<Button onClick={() => {setState1(foo); setState2(bar)}}></Button
```

Or you could add them to a function and then call the function inline

```
function multipleStates(foo, bar){
    setState1(foo)
    setState2(bar)
}

<Button onClick={() => multipleState(foo, bar)}></Button>
```

I'm not sure if that is too broad of an answer for you, hopefully I haven't misinterpreted your question.

Comment: HI, no you understood the question.  The complication I have is that my close for the modal is set outside the modal.  I will update the question to show this, but the hint component has the setState for the modal, so a setState on the close doesn't work here

Comment: Actually got this working - and as silly as it sounded, I had to put a semi colon between the states.  That was it

Comment: Oh dang, I completely forgot about that! Good on you for working it out. Its always the little things